# How to change an confidential issue in gitlab to public?

Tags: gitlab, issue-tracking

I accidentally created a confidential issue in the gitlab. But, now I need to change it back to the public? Can anyone help me out?

I tried to find the answers on the youtube and Web, but I can't find any.

Comment: Are there any new insights about this? ( It's April 2023 and still the same problem here. )

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [Modify issue confidentiality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/confidential_issues.html#modify-issue-confidentiality)

> locate the Confidentiality section in the sidebar and select Edit.
> A popup should appear and give you the option to turn on or turn off confidentiality.
>
> [image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/img/turn_off_confidentiality_v15_1.png]